# Using dput() with large sample size in R

Tags: r, output

Specifically i am trying to create a reproducible example with a data.frame of [1376,6] dimensions using dput() but run out of space in the output window to copy and paste the results.

Is there a way of increasing the buffer size of the output window OR
Could anyone suggest an alternative method here ?

Thanks

Barry

Comment: save to txt file and upload that to google drive, dropbox, etc.  post link to file.

Comment: Some other possibilities: Take the top 20 or 30 rows with `dput(head(dat, n=20))`. Randomly sample the rows with `dput(dat[sample(1:nrow(dat), 30, replace=FALSE), ])`. Build an entirely made up data.frame with functions like `rnorm`, `rpois`, `sample`, `rep`, `seq`, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can always write the result of `dput` to a file:

```
dput(rnorm(20), 'test.txt')
```

See `?dput` for details.

Comment: I require the complete dataframe to be used in the reproducible example as the issue is R is hanging in a monte carlo simulation so i think writing to a text file and dropboxing is my best solution.  Many thanks for all the good suggestions though.